# How to access class method in C++ function

Tags: c++

I'm writing a simlpe c++ programm which displays current date using ctime library and asks a user to input any year to compare it with the current year. After that it says "Valid" (if input year is less that current year) or "Invalid" (if input year is greater that current year).
But I got an issue that I can't solve on my own. Every time an error pops up: **cannot call member funnction without object.**
Here's the code:
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"    
using namespace std;    
void date();

int main()
{
    Header aCl;
    aCl.setYear(2010)
    int year;
    cin >> year;
    aCl.isValid()

}
```

functions.cpp

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;

void Header::setYear(int val){
    year = val;
}

void Header::isValid(int &passed)
{
    if (passed > Header::year)
        cout << "Valid" << endl;
    else
        cout <<"Invalid!" << endl;
}


void date(){
    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm *now = localtime(&t);
    int currYear = now->tm_year + 1900; // Year is # years since 1900
    cout << "Current date is " << currYear << endl;

    Header::isValid(currYear);
}
```

header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H


#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Header {
    public:
        int year;
        void setYear(int val);
        void isValid(int &passed);
};

#endif
```

Comment: Please edit your question indicating which line the error occurs, additionally `isValid` takes a param which you've not passed, you're also accessing `isValid` using the scope operator `::` but it's not a static method so this is also invalid

Comment: `date()` is a non-member function that calls `isValid()` which *is* a member-function without an instance of `Header`.

Comment: Your `Header` class is halfway between two possible ways it could work. Is each `Header` supposed to have a `year`? Or is there supposed to be just one `year`? Is `setYear` supposed to operate on a single `Header` and set its year? Or is supposed to set the only year for all `Header`s? If there were two `Header`s, could they have different years?

Comment: `Header::isValid(currYear);` is incorrect. Only static methods can be called like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
aCl.isValid()
```

Should be:

```
aCl.isValid(year);
```

And

```
void Header::isValid(int &passed)
{
    if (passed > Header::year)
        cout << "Valid" << endl;
    else
        cout <<"Invalid!" << endl;
}
```

should be:

```
void Header::isValid(int &passed)
{
    if (passed > year)
        cout << "Valid" << endl;
    else
        cout <<"Invalid!" << endl;
}
```

I'm making some assumptions about what you intended, but I think this is most likely what you meant.